# How can I get AngularJS ui router to work with fullPage.js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, fullpage.js

I am creating a full page scrolling web app. I have something like this for a view

```
<div class="section">Section 1</div> 
<div class="section">Section 2</div> 
<div class="section">Section 3</div>
```

And my route looks like this:

```
.state('home', {
            url: '/',

            templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
              return $templateCache.get('partials/home.html');
            }
        });
```

I want my routes to look like this:

```
.state('home', {
            url: '/',

            templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
              return $templateCache.get('partials/home.html');
            }
        })
        .state('section1', {//code}),
        .state('section2', {//code}),
        .state('section3', {//code});
```

My URL are formatted: `www.example.com#section1, www.example.com#section2, etc.`

How do I get the route to change each time a user scrolls to a different section?

Comment: take a look at http://hellsan631.github.io/angular-fullpage.js/#/main

Comment: @ppollono I did, but it only uses 1 route like I am doing.